# For C++ strings is using compare method or relational operators better

Tags: c++, string, performance, compare, readability

I am working with a lot of strings in this project and currently in my code I have a lot of `if (StringA.compare(StringB) == 0)`. I am wondering if replacing the comparisons in the if statements with `(StringA == StringB)` would make the code easier to read? Also, is using the relational operators instead of the compare method preferred by c++ coders? Additionally does using the relational operators take more time to run? And if so, how much extra time?

Comment: They're equivalent in speed and more readable. Use `compare` if you actually need the ternary result.

Comment: @chris the ternary result as in (condition) ? (if_true) : (if_false)

Comment: No, the ternary (think three, as opposed to binary) result as in <0, 0, >0. Like if you need to hand that off to some function that takes one of those.

Comment: To expound on what chris said, if you are only checking one condition, just use `(stringa == stringb)`, then the relational operators are more readable.  If, for example, you intend on doing  something like `if ( stringa == stringb )` followed by a `if (stringa < stringb)`, then there _may_ be a performance difference in using `stringa.compare(stringb)` (a good optimizing compiler may make the same transformation).

Comment: Cool than I will convert all of my code to 'if ( stringa == stringb )' for better readability. Thank you Chris and Ken P

Comment: If I have multiple string comparisons in one if statement which is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use relational operators with parentheses for stacking operators. Use relational operators for all situations where you do not need the result of `compare`, which can produce `<0,0,0<` results depending on the difference. Speed is equivalent.